# Deserialise missing XML attribute to Nullable type

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

There are various solutions for **serialising** `Nullable` types on SO but what i need is a solution for **deserialising** to a nullable type. The Specified and ShouldSerailise techniques dont seem to apply to deserialising.

So if my XML document is missing an attribute I want the int in the class to be null not 0.

Unfortunately you cant serialise directly to a nullable int because the serializes throws a reflection error.

So in the example below i want `result2.SomeInt` to be null and `result1.SomeInt = 12`

```
class TestProgram
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Result));

        Stream xmlStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(docWithVal().InnerXml));
        var result1 = (Result)deserializer.Deserialize(xmlStream);

        Stream xmlStream2 = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(docWithoutVal().InnerXml));
        var result2 = (Result)deserializer.Deserialize(xmlStream2);
    }

    public static XmlDocument docWithoutVal()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(@"<Result/>");
        return doc;
    }

    public static XmlDocument docWithVal()
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(@"<Result SomeInt = ""12""/>");
        return doc;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int? SomeInt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Even if you use `int` property in place of `int?`second serialization won't work since `SomeInt` attribute is missing from the XML.

Comment: Do you want if value of `SomeInt` is 0, corresponding value should be null?

Comment: Unless you use a custom (de)serializer, I guess you will have problems trying to serialize a Nullable property into an XmlAttribute. It should be XmlElement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can infact use the Specified techniques after deserialization. Modify your `Result` class this way:

```
[Serializable]
public class Result
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool SomeIntSpecified;
}
```

Now use this logic after deserialization for `Nullable` types:

```
var value = SomeIntSpecified ? SomeInt : null;
```

---

OR you can also implement `IXmlSerializable` in your `Result` class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Result : IXmlSerializable
{
    public int? SomeInt { get; set; }

    #region IXmlSerializable members

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        if (SomeInt != null) { writer.WriteValue(writer); }
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(reader.GetAttribute("SomeInt"), out result))
            SomeInt = result;
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return (null);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Reference: [Using XmlSerializer to deserialize into a Nullable](http://alexscordellis.blogspot.com/2008/11/using-xmlserializer-to-deserialize-into.html)

Comment: is there a way of doing this without implementing IXmlSerializable. Id dont want to duplicate all my properties inside readxml and using reflection would presumably be a bad idea.